# External access to port 8080 is not working (Windows Server 2012 VM in Azure)

Tags: azure

The page is served on port 8080. It works locally (http://localhost:8080). (Also tried port 80, no avail.)

I have already disabled the firewall.

I have already configured the inbound rule of the security group in Azure, this way:
[image]

Error is:

```
$ telnet 13.76.139.111 8080
Trying 13.76.139.111...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888292/routing-tcp-traffic-to-port-8080-on-azure-vm/34937182#34937182), make sure to set the source port range as `*`. Clients use a source port number allocated from a pool of [ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).

(Also explained in a comment from Ralph Squillace replying feedback over [an article about how to do it in a classic VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/#comment-2443704166).)

Comment: Still didn't work for me

Comment: I had the same issue today and fix was to enable the firewall rule for port 8080 in Windows Server as well. So, we need to enable access in the network security group as well as in Windows Firewall.